# Obtaining list of proxies

Tags: iptables, proxy

It there a source where I can obtain a large up to date list of proxy ips? I would like to limit users votes on a website if they are using proxy.

Comment: That sounds like a classic case of whack-a-mole to me.

Comment: @Sirex It's not the best solution, but I need to detect as many proxies as I can to minimize vote rigging. Do you have a better solution for detecting proxy?

Comment: dont rely on the connection used to detect vote rigging ? Use some form of authentication, surely ?

Comment: @Sirex It's not a type of site where you would be confirming user's real identity, just votes on comments, posts etc... I just want to minimize the effect of multiple account voters.

Comment: by multiple account, can you not just log the usernames that have already voted and go from that ? It sounds like alot of hassle on their part to try and make multiple accounts on the site just to vote something up a few times, and equal amount of effort on your part to track an ever changing list of proxy addresses.

Comment: @Sirex, I'm already tracking that, if a vote is cast form a certain ip, next vote will be balanced with a auto downvote. But if users use proxy servers, then I can not do that.

Answer (score 3):

Instead, restrict access based on the presence of the X-Forwarded-For: header.

Comment: This is likely the best bet. It's not fool-proof, but its a lot better than tracking a proxy list.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that there are many private proxies that do not add those headers.

Comment: I highly suspect you're over engineering a solution to a problem that doesn't exist. In reality how many people actually bother to vote on things, let alone use proxies to game the system ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use cookies and/or [evercookies](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) to track which users have voted before and/or which users have been seen using known proxies (such as those identified by the `X-Forwarded-For:` header).

I suspect this will be far more reliable than trying to find a list of "all" public proxy servers.